# Filter table html usign javascript in a APP SCRIPT project

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a project in APP SCRIPT of GOOGLE SHEETS whit a table in HTML that display data from a document of GOOGLE SHEETS. The table include a input box for filter ... but this search in the column 2 only... I want that this input search in the all columns ... I tried change this part of de code .cells[1] with  .cells[1,2,3,4 ...] ... but dont runs correctly ...
How modify this code?

Thank u

```
function onInputChange(){
let inputText = document.getElementById("input-search").value.toString().toLowerCase();

let tableBody = document.getElementById("cursos");
let tableRows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");


for(let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++){


let textoConsulta = tableRows[i].cells[1].textContent.toString().toLowerCase();
if( textoConsulta.indexOf(inputText) === -1 ) {
tableRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
} else {
tableRows[i].style.visibility = "";
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the code so that it searches in all columns instead of just column 2, you can iterate over each cell within a row and check if the input text is present in any of the cells. Here's an updated version of your code that performs a search across all columns:

```
function onInputChange() {
  let inputText = document.getElementById("input-search").value.toString().toLowerCase();
  let tableBody = document.getElementById("cursos");
  let tableRows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    let rowCells = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    let foundMatch = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < rowCells.length; j++) {
      let cellText = rowCells[j].textContent.toString().toLowerCase();
      if (cellText.indexOf(inputText) !== -1) {
        foundMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (foundMatch) {
      tableRows[i].style.visibility = "";
    } else {
      tableRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
    }
  }
}
```

In this updated code, we introduce an inner loop that iterates over each cell within a row (rowCells). For each cell, we check if the input text is present (cellText.indexOf(inputText) !== -1). If a match is found in any cell, we set foundMatch to true and break out of the inner loop.

Finally, after examining all the cells in a row, we check the value of foundMatch to determine whether to show or hide the row (tableRows[i].style.visibility).

Make sure to update the #cursos ID in the HTML code to match the actual ID of your table element.